# How to clean up the temp folders of RAD 8?

Tags: java, classpath, ibm-rad

I am receiving the javax.servlet.UnavailableException: (SRVE0203E). As far as I know, this means that not all libraries that I use in the classpath for compiling with RAD are present in the runtime classpath. The error message from the log file outputs the runtime classpath and when I compare it with my compile classpath I can't find missing libraries. The only difference is that the runtime classpath contains 2 old libraries, which I deleted last week from my system. They are before the new versions, which means, that the integrated app server tries to use them.

For example:

```
class-path: [C:\workspace\MYEAR\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;
C:\workspace\MYEAR\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;
C:\workspace\MYEAR\commons-collections-3.1.jar;
C:\workspace\MYEAR\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;...................]
```

How can I delete those old references? They are perhaps defined in a file somewhere in a temp folder... That's why I'd like to delete all RAD 8 temp folders.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Start the RAD with clean option.
Ofcourse I assume that you have the correct class paths and libraries now.

So go to the IBM install directory that has a eclipse.exe

and type this in command prompt:

eclipse.exe -clean

this should take some time in starting up but it will mostlikely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your WAR modules, check:

- Classpath: `project/.classpath`
- [Deployment assembly](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.javaee.doc/topics/cdeploymentassembly.html): `project/.setings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`
- Bundled dependencies: `project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`

In your EAR, check:

- Deployment assembly: `project/.setings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`
- [Deployment descriptor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/com.ibm.javaee.doc/topics/tjaddmod.html): `project/META-INF/application.xml`